# How to run Jenkins-cli in bash

Tags: java, bash, git, docker, jenkins

below docker script should download jenkins, then jenkins-cli.jar and run that jar in bash.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y  software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y && \
    apt-get update && \
    echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get install -f -y oracle-java9-installer && \
    apt install -y default-jre curl wget git nano; \
    apt-get clean


# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get -y update  && \
    apt-get -yqq --no-install-recommends install git bzip2 curl unzip && \
    apt-get update

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr
ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

# copy jenkins war file to the container
ADD http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/2.107.1/jenkins.war /opt/jenkins.war
RUN chmod 644 /opt/jenkins.war
ENV JENKINS_HOME /jenkins

# configure the container to run jenkins, mapping container port 8080 to that host port

RUN mkdir /jenkins/
RUN echo 2.107.1 > /jenkins/jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state
RUN echo 2.107.1 > /jenkins/jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion
ENTRYPOINT ["nohup","java", "-jar", "/opt/jenkins.war"]
EXPOSE 8080
VOLUME /jenkins

#jenkins-cli installation
ENV JENKINS_URL "http://192.168.99.100:8080"
RUN mkdir -p /jcli
RUN chmod 644 /jcli
RUN curl --insecure -OL http://192.168.99.100:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar \
   --output /jcli/jenkins-cli.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/jcli/jenkins-cli.jar","-noCertificateCheck","-noKeyAuth"]
```

when i run "docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash " it is leading me to bash then when i run "java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://192.168.99.100:8080/ help" in bash its showing ERROR( in screen shot)
[image: ERROR]

When i test some command in bash its working(screenshot shared)
[image: test]

**QUESTION**

- AM i doing wrong in passing jar file to bash
- How can i run it?

**MY ASSUMPTION**
jenkins-cli.jar is not downloading where my jenkins is hosted
i may need to run jenkins in background and need to go through it to download jenkins-cli.jar which i do manually
or bash is not running inside container
or jenkis and jenkins-cli Entry point is conflicting?
**How can i do that???**

*Help me to run that jenkins-cli.jar file to run in git bash*, so i can run any command used to build my jenkins job
Thank u in advance

Comment: I know this is old and you are past it but for anyone coming here. I believe the problem is using `ADD` in the Dockerfile with an HTTP link. I believe you have to run a `wget -o http://remoteFileLocation localFileLocation/fileName`. And then you don't need the `ADD`.